# How to get variable of a textbox in a non-angular page using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to test a non-angular page using Protractor.

I am getting one input value of non-angular page with:

```
console.log(browser.driver.findElement(by.ID('username')).getText());
```

It's displaying like

> [object][object]

I need to get the value of text field. How can i get that?

Answer (score 1):

The webdriver looks like it should be finding the element correctly, however because of the way  the [control flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) works with protractor you are not able to access the value from a log.

The expect statements normally unravel these responses but you could do something like this if you wanted to see it before that point or modify the value before the expect:

```
var txArea = browser.driver.findElement(by.ID('username')).getText();
txArea = txArea.then(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
expect(txArea).toEqual('textbox text');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getText` returns (a promised solved with) text nodes instead of text value.

> **The result of getText from an input element is always empty**
>
> This is a [webdriver quirk](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/12bcmvwhcm/extarcting-text-from-the-input-field). `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements always have empty getText values. Instead, try `element.getAttribute('value')`.

form [Protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty)